# BigQuery: Extract everything between first and fourth underscore

Tags: string, split, google-bigquery, extract

So lets say I have this string "this_is_a_string_test"

I want to extract "is_a_string".

How would I do that? Using SPLIT and OFFSET I can very easily extract a single part, but I wanna extract everything between the first and fourth underscore.
I suppose I could use CONCAT, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Try [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract):

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('this_is_a_string_test', r'.*_(.+_.+_.+)_.*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider also below approach

```
select col, 
  (select string_agg(word, '_') 
  from unnest(split(col, '_')) word with offset 
  where offset between 1 and 3
  ) extraction
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I did not know this was possible as well. Learned something, thanks :)!